# How to select only one field where id number is the same sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is as follows

```
bugID  | name  | description  | comment
----------------------------------------------------------------
1      | bug1  | first bug    | <p></p>
1      | bug1  | first bug    | <p>this is the first bug</p>
1      | bug1  | first bug    | <p>this needs fixing</p>
2      | bug2  | second bug   | <p>this is the second bug</p>
3      | bug3  | third bug    | <p>bug number 3</p>
```

I want to get the records back as follows if I do a select * from this table

```
1, bug1, first bug, <p></p>, <p>this is the first bug</p>, <p>this needs fixing</p>
2, bug2, second bug, <p>this is the second bug</p>
3, bug3, third bug, <p>bug number 3</p>
```

Is there a way I can do this in SQL?

Comment: which kind of DBMS are you using? MySql-SlqServer-SQLite-Oracle....

Comment: Sorry its SQL server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server

```
SELECT bugID,
       name,
       description,
       STUFF(( SELECT ',' + comment 
                  FROM Table1 I Where I.bugID= O.bugID
                FOR
                  XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '')
FROM   Table1 O
GROUP BY bugID,
       name,
       description
```