# How to strip/change certain characters in a column sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used a the following select statements in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, BugID, Summary, Description, reportedDate, versionID, versionName, BugResolution, IssueStatusId, BugStatus, BugType, BugPriority, ComponentName, ReportedBy, 
STUFF(( SELECT ',' + Comment 
                  FROM lbbugnet.dbo.report_view I Where I.bugID= O.bugID
                FOR
                  XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') as Comment, 
    Code, IssueResolutionId FROM lbbugnet.dbo.report_view O
    WHERE BugID BETWEEN @fromID AND @toID
    ORDER BY BugID ASC
```

This selects the columns that are needed and stuffs the comments into the same column instead of separate records. Because the value is converted to XML the text

> `<p></p>`

has been changed to

> `&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;,`

is there any way I could prevent this from happening or change it back after it has been selected?

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17988593/1578604).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Name, 
    BugID, 
    Summary, 
    Description, 
    reportedDate, 
    versionID, 
    versionName, 
    BugResolution, 
    IssueStatusId, 
    BugStatus, 
    BugType, 
    BugPriority, 
    ComponentName, 
    ReportedBy,
    Comment.value('.', 'varchar(max)') Comments,
    Code, 
    IssueResolutionId       
FROM   
    (SELECT 
        Name, BugID, Summary, Description, reportedDate, versionID, versionName, BugResolution, IssueStatusId, BugStatus, BugType, BugPriority, ComponentName, ReportedBy,
        CAST(STUFF(( SELECT ',' + Comment 
                      FROM lbbugnet.dbo.report_view I Where I.bugID= O.bugID
                    FOR
                      XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') as xml) as Comment,
        Code, IssueResolutionId         
    FROM 
      lbbugnet.dbo.report_view O
    WHERE 
      BugID BETWEEN @fromID AND @toID) A
ORDER BY 
    BugID ASC
```